# Dynamically created kendo datepicker is not working

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker, telerik, kendo-datepicker

Here is my html,

```
            <div id="replicate">
               <div id="student">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label class="control-label" for="">Name</label>
                            <textarea id="" name="" class="form-control" col="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label class="control-label" for="">Date</label>
                            <input id="" name="" class="form-control kendo_datepicker" value="" placeholder="" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               </div>
```

On button click am adding the  to the #replicate div.Datepicker is not working for dynamically added control.
Here is my function

```
    function add(student, count) {
    var dat = $('#' + student).html();
    $('#replicate').append('')  // my logic

    var datepicker = $("input.kendo_datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
    datepicker.setOptions({
        min: new Date()
    });
}
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Kendo template to house the HTML you want duplicated.

```
<script id="datepicker-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div id="student">
    <!--More HTML to be duplicated-->
</script>
```

On each click, you can append that HTML to your #replicate div element and call the kendoDatePicker() function on the lastly created datepicker control.

Here is one example of how you could do that:
http://jsfiddle.net/1yje5u9n/

Answer (score 1):

To initiate a kendo `datePicker`, try this:

```
$("input.kendo_datepicker").kendoDatePicker({});
```

This worked for me, hope this works for you!

Comment: tried this , its not working for me. can you create an example for me.

Comment: in the example, want to add multiple date controls on the click action,from the code was not able to add dynamically

Comment: Where is the variable `data` coming from?

Comment: actually that is student, when they click add button, we are appending the student div html to replicate div.